# How to update other appointments in my calender through ews

Tags: asp.net-web-api, exchangewebservices

I am sync my outlook calender with my application through ews and also other appointments that are not created by me.

The issue is , I am updating outlook calendar from my application. When I try to update other appointments that are not created by me are throwing error.

Is there way in ews to update those appointments? Since outlook have an option to update(save & close ) the appointments ?

Please advice on this

Answer (score 1):

No as that breaks the business logic eg an attendee can't update a Meeting organised by somebody else. You need to create a Meeting update from the Organiser copy of the appointment and then accept that on the user behalf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633648(v=exchg.80).aspx if you want to maintain the attendees Calendars integrity.